# Deleted Pod Logs

Tags: kubernetes

I recently had an event that resulted in my pod being evicted and in order to quickly reestablish service I proceeded to delete the pod which resulted in a new one being spun up.

Is there any way to describe or retrieve logs from a deleted pod so that I can perform RCA on why the pod was evicted in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If it is just previous one you can try **--previous** flag with your logs command. More details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#basic-logging-in-kubernetes)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, once you manually delete K8s Pod, the corresponded containers and their relevant logging data will be purged as well, thus `--previous` flag works only if the previous container instance still exists in Pod.

> If true, print the logs for the previous instance of the container in
>   a pod if it exists.

You might consider in future implementing log aggregation software like [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/), [Logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout#logspout) or [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/introduction.html) data collector in [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack) stack.